# Set default mode in gcalctool

Tags: gconf, conversion, gcalctool

I often use **gcalctool**, to quickly convert a number between "binary/hex/decimal". For this I find the "Programming" mode of gcalctool useful. I can select this using *"Mode → Programming*" from the toolbar.

However, this gcalctool setting does not appear to be preserved between restarting gcalctool.
Is there a way I can force this? E.g entering something in `~/.gcalctoolrc`

Answer (score 2):

This was a [bug in Ubuntu 10.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gcalctool/+bug/602238) but as you can see from the bug report, it should have been fixed with version 5.31.4-0ubuntu4.

What version are you using (in a gnome-terminal, run `apt-cache policy gcalctool`)?

Have you tried reinstalling it (run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall gcalctool`)?

Comment: I am using version 5.32.0-0ubuntu4 (thanks for the command). I tried reinstalling, but this did not fix it for me.

Comment: This works on my home computer (regular single-user Ubuntu 10.10 install), but not on my work computer (my user is a NIS user, and I have local root access). I think it is to do with my NIS user not having access to files created by the local root account, during an `apt-get install`, since these files were created with umask 007. I will try and find-out what these files are and change the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and have gcalctool version 5.32.

I gave up and installed qcalculate instead which can do binary/hex/decimal conversions.

More a workaround than a solution I'm afraid.